# Передать список (list) из Python в Prolog PySwip

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, prolog, swi-prolog

Я пишу программу использую Prolog и Python, используя библиотеку PySwip. Мне необходимо передать список из Python в Prolog. На данный момент я сделал это так:

```
from pyswip import Prolog
p = Prolog()
p.assertz("fruits([apple,banana,orange])")  # Создание списка
p.assertz("result(X) :- fruits(L), member(X, L)")  # Правило вхождения элемента в список
print(list(p.query("result(orange).")))  # Возвращает True, если такой элемент есть в списке
```

Но мне необходимо сделать список отдельным объектом, потому что мне необходимо совершить с ним определенные действия, то того как отправить в пролог. Я не знаю как это реализовать.

```
from pyswip import Prolog
p = Prolog()
fruits = [apple,banana,orange]
p.assertz("Как передать в Prolog список fruits???") # Я не знаю как это реализовать.
```

Подскажите, как это можно сделать? Всем заранее спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге решение найдено. Опубликую его, вдруг кому - нибудь поможет. Необходимо просто передавать список в запрос в виде строки, f-строки с этим справляются лучше всего. Также на данном примере проверено, что это работает и с русскими символами.

```
from pyswip import Prolog
p = Prolog()
fruits = ['слива', 'груша']
p.assertz(f"фрукты({fruits})")  # Задаем список
p.assertz("result(X) :- фрукты(L), member(X, L)")  # Задаем правило для проверки вхождения в список
print(list(p.query("result('слива').")))  # Выполняем запрос, если список не пустой, значит true
```